# Как реализовать Bottom Sheet, от размера и движения которого зависят компоненты выше?

Tags: android, recyclerview, material-design, bottom-sheet

Мне нужно реализовать приблизительно такой UI функционал.
[image: Collapsed Bottom Sheet]
Это `layout` с закрытым `Bottom Sheet`.

[image: Expand Bottom Sheet]
Это `layout` с открытым `Bottom Sheet`.

Я реализовал `Bottom Sheet` как в макете, но моя проблема в том, что `Bottom Sheet` вылазит поверх `Recycler View`. Я же хочу сделать как в дизайне - чтобы при открытии `Bottom Sheet` мой `Recycler View` динамически уменьшался в размере. Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом `Bottom Sheet` можно задать такое поведение, как мне узнать растояние от `Toolbar` до верхней части `Bottom Sheet` и как мне динамически с анимацией уменьшать `Recycler View` при открытии `Bottom Sheet`.